# TextInputLayout hint color not changing after upgrading android support library to 28.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

After upgrading the android support library in my project to 28.0.0, I can't change the hint color of a custom TextInput

I have tried changing the color by using a drawable depending of states, changing the textColor attribute, changing the textColorHint attribute... None of them are working, but if change other hint attributes, such as text size, it works.

**This situation only occurs when the EditText is not editable**

My current hint style:

```
<style name="TextInputHint" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textinput_hint_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize14</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">4</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    </style>
```

And the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/northTexasGreen" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/lightSlateGray" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: How so you set this on the TextInputLayout?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I'm setting it by using `setHintAppearance` method in my custom TextInput class

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working on 28.0.0

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputHint">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Checking hint color"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<style name="TextInputHint" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textinput_hint_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize14</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">4</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/northTexasGreen" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/lightSlateGray" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This is the way I set it, but when I set the focusable attribute of the EditText to false, the color is not the one I want

Comment: If you set focusable to false, the color can never switch to focusable state. Try setting editable to false, if that achieves what you needed.

Comment: This is not the problem, debugging the code I have seen that internally it changes the color of the hint correctly, but nevertheless it is still shown as if it were disabled